# Classes or closures for simple things in Python

Tags: python, performance, class, memory, closures

I would like to know more about the functions "with memory" implemented as classes vs closures.

Consider the (very) simple example:

```
def constant(value):
    def _inner():
        return value
    return _inner
x = constant(5)
print(x())
```

vs.

```
class Constant():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def __call__(self):
        return self._value
y = Constant(5)
print(y())
```

Is the performance and memory consumption of any of these better? Using slots will make the class perform better?

Thanks,

Hernan

Ps.- I know that in this extremely simple example, probably it does not matter. But I am interested in more complex functions that will be called a big number of times or that will be instantiated many times.

Comment: What are your performance constraints?

Comment: Between 10-100 functions are instantiated, and each is called around a million times

Comment: The rule of thumb you want is: never guess, always profile.

Comment: Python does have some not so small overhead for function calling.  I say "not so small" only when you're dealing with high-performance areas.  Then again, if you're in this realm it's time to bust out the C API or Boost.Python.  As @Duncan says, profile first.

Answer (score 8):

In Python 2.6 I get the following:

```
def foo(x):
    def bar():
        return x
    return bar

b = foo(4)
b.__sizeof__()
>>> 44
```

But using a class:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x
    def __call__(self):
        return self.x

c = foo(4)
c.__sizeof__()
>>> 16
```

Which looks like the function version is a larger memory footprint.

Comment: Same result in Python 3 too, except that the function takes up `52` instead of `44`.

Comment: You missed some of the footprint. The first option creates a new function object, but that also has an associated `__closure__` to hold the value (`__sizeof__` returns 16) and a `__dict__` (`__sizeof__` says 124). The instance also has a `__dict__` associated with it. Of course if you really need to squeeze memory then use `__slots__` on the class.

Answer (score 3):

I'd write the more complex functions and profile them.

Comment: I agree, but there must be a rule of thumb if you know the internals of the python interpreter (which I don't)

Comment: Well, sure, you could dig into the internals (which are subject to change), and try to figure out what will theoretically work better, but profilers exist for a reason. I'm reminded of Knuth's warning: "Beware of bugs in the above code. I have only proven it correct, not tested it." For most of us mere mortals, testing or profiling is the right way to go.

Answer (score -1):

If you want performance and only want access to values, then it would be best to use a built-in data type such as a tuple for best performance